# Binary search problem with my code....please look into my following problem?

Tags: c++, search, binary-search

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int list[25],vote[25];
bool found;
int count,first,mid,last;
char condition;
double high = 0,total=0;
string searchitem,name[25],winner;
cout <<"How many names?" <<endl;
cin>>count;
cout <<" Enter the "<<count<< " candidates last name and the number of votes received " <<endl;
for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    cin >>name[i];
    cin >> vote[i];
    total = total+vote[i];

}

cout <<"Candidate names ,number of votes and their percentage of votes are ..."<<endl;
for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    cout << name[i]<<endl;
    cout << vote[i]<<endl;
    cout << (vote[i]*100)/total<<endl;
    if(vote[i]>high)
    {
        high = vote[i];
     winner = name[i];
    }

}
cout << " The winner of the election is " << winner << endl;

cout << "Do you have anything more to do?y/n?" << endl;
cin >> condition;
while (condition=='y' || condition=='Y')
{
found = false;
cout<<"Enter name you want to search \n";
cin>>searchitem;
first=0;
last=count-1;
while ((first<=count)&&!found)
{
    mid=(first+last)/2;
    if (name[mid]==searchitem)
    {
        found=true;
        total =  total-vote[mid];
        cout << "Enter the new number of votes for " << name[mid] << endl;
        cin >> vote[mid];
        total = total + vote[mid];
    }
    else if (name[mid]>searchitem)
    {
        last=mid-1;
    }
    else first=mid+1;
}
if (!found)
{
    cout<<" Sorry that name was not found \n";
}

cout <<"Candidate names ,number of votes and their percentage of votes are ..."<<endl;
high = 0;
for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    cout << name[i]<<endl;
    cout << vote[i]<<endl;
    cout << (vote[i]*100)/total<<endl;
    if(vote[i]>high)
    {
        high = vote[i];
     winner = name[i];
    }
}
cout << " The winner is " << winner << endl;

cout << "Do you have anything more to do?y/n? "<<endl;
cin >> condition;
}
}
```

Alright.Now I have been trying to experiment with this and when there are 5 names involved, Im able to alter the third and the fourth name's votes and display the results.
But when I try searching for the first,second and the last name my program just halts!
Why is this happening???And a solution can help save me time from trying to break a wall with bare hands.

Comment: 1)This isn't really a question.
2) Split the function in to sub functions, it's too big.
3) Use a debugger or print statements to work out what's going on yourself

Comment: 1) There clearly is a question in my question. 2) I asked for a solution I can use in my code and not to change my code with an entirely new method.

Comment: Your question is not much more than "here's some code i wrote, fix it for me". If you understand enough to have written the above, you should be able to debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ((first<=count)&&!found)
```

should be

```
while ((first<=last)&&!found)
```

Comment: that doesnt work...now whenever I try searching for the first,second and last name it shows as the name was not found.

Comment: Are you entering the names in sorted order ?

Comment: Yes I wanted to know about that..I kinda forgot how .But should I put the names according to A,B,C..etc order?

Comment: Binary search only works on sorted array. Since you are applying the binary search on the `name` array. It must be sorted.

Comment: @Surya binary search needs an ordered sequence.

Comment: Thank you.I put it in the sorted manner.Thats what I missed .